# Adding repositories using QGIS Resource Sharing

Tags: repository

I am trying to add a git repository to Q using QGIS Resource Sharing for seismic data analysis and am unsure why I am unable to do it. It comes up with an error (below) saying the server cannot be found. I haven't used the Resource Sharing plugin before, so it could be that I'm doing it incorrectly.

The repo I am trying to add is public (the URL is https://github.com/obspy/obspy, I am using https://github.com/obspy/obspy.git in the URL line).

[image: error_screenshot1]
[image: error_screenshot2]

Answer (score 1):

To add a git repository using the [QGIS Resource Sharing plugin](https://qgis-contribution.github.io/QGIS-ResourceSharing/usage/installing-collection.html), the respository must be a QGIS resource collection.  You can't add just any git repository using the plugin.  Collections have a [specific structure](https://qgis-contribution.github.io/QGIS-ResourceSharing/authoring/repository-structure.html) that allows them to be understood by the plugin.

The [`obspy`](https://github.com/obspy/obspy) repository is not a collection and can't be added by the plugin. If you want to add the `obspy` package to the python that QGIS uses, ask another question and include your operating system and how/where you installed QGIS.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help. I'll do that now!